# Error is not display php

Tags: php, mongodb

i have a login form, and when i wrong password i don't have this error:

> "your are not register or your password is wrong !"

I have nothing, there is nothing that appears.

this is my code php, my data is mongodb :

```
<?php



if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Login"){
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $error    = array();
    // Username Validation
    if (empty($username)) {
         $error[] = " <h2>  complete username </h2>";
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
         $error[] = " <h2> complete password</h2> ";
    }

        // connexion data
    if (count($error) == 0)
    {
        $host               = 'localhost';
        $database_name      = 'Projet';
        $database_user_name = '';
        $database_password  = '';
        $connection         = new MongoClient();

        if ($connection)
        {
            // select data
            $database = $connection->$database_name;

            // Select collection
            $collection = $database->reg_users;
            $user_data  = array(
                "username" => $username,
                "password" => md5($password)
            );
            $result     = $collection->find($user_data);
            if ($result>0)
            {
                header("Location: Articles.php");
                foreach ($result as $doc)
                 {
                    $_SESSION['email']    = $doc['email'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $doc['username'];
                 }

             }else{

                      $error[] = " <h2> your are not register or your password is wrong !  </h2>";
                }

            } else {
                      $error[] = " no mongodb connection";
                }
        }  

         if(count($error) > 0) 
        {
             foreach($error as $e)
             {
                echo $e;
             }
        }
}
```

Comment: you posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/30107997/

Comment: because i have update the code, can you help me

Comment: you should tend to the answers given in your other question and update your other question with the code you are now using and marked as an edit under your code while not overwriting it.

Comment: oh okay sorry i'm going to make that

Comment: however, you didn't do like I asked. You overwrote your entire question/code and did not mark as **Edit"** here is my **new** code.....// you will need to tell others that you have updated your question with the new code.